# How do I setup my Conexant USB modem type 0572:1340 in Ubuntu 18.04 to send and receive faxes?

Tags: software-installation, permissions, usb-modem

The driver has been installed but -- to start with -- I don't have access to the tty8 port where minicom finds the modem.

`minicom` output is:

```
minicom: cannot open /dev/tty8: Permission denied
```

`ls -l /dev/tty?` output is:

```
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 0 Jun  7 10:30 /dev/tty0
crw--w---- 1 aris tty 4, 1 Jun  7 10:30 /dev/tty1
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 2 Jun  7 10:30 /dev/tty2
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 3 Jun  7 10:30 /dev/tty3
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 4 Jun  7 10:30 /dev/tty4
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 5 Jun  7 10:30 /dev/tty5
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 6 Jun  7 10:30 /dev/tty6
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 7 Jun  7 10:30 /dev/tty7
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 8 Jun  7 10:30 /dev/tty8
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 9 Jun  7 10:30 /dev/tty9
```

In Efax-gtk I get the "Permission denied" error, too. Also in LibreOffice Writer's Print menu I don't get a Fax option. Only "my printer" and the "print to file" options. Could you please guide me to change the permission for that port and anything further I need to do so that I can have fax functionality with that modem? Thanks.

PS. I used this modem with Windows to send and receive faxes just fine but I migrated to Ubuntu a couple of weeks ago and I have a lot to learn, which I am enjoying.

Comment: I did some searching and found the following commands which I used and now I have access to the port:  `sudo adduser <user name> dialout` and `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER`. I just don't know which one did the trick. The port is still under root.  I only added myself to the group that can use that port.

Comment: I checked the modem this morning. It is working fine, both sending and receiving faxes. My question was answered so I am going to answer it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I used 2 commands: `sudo adduser <user name> dialout` and `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER`. I can now send and receive faxes.